# Why does MessageBox show the window in my created desktop, but AllocConsole show it in the previous?

Tags: c++, winapi, console

When a thread is changed to a different desktop new consoles created with AllocConsole() appear in the original desktop. Message boxes and other windows created appear in the new desktop as would be expected, but console windows do not. The following code is a windows application example, however it still the result is the same whether or not it is a console application.

```
#include <Windows.h>

HDESK hDesk;

DWORD WINAPI Testing(void *)
{
    SetThreadDesktop(hDesk);
    AllocConsole();
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Test"), NULL, MB_OK); //This will show on the new desktop
    FreeConsole();
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    hDesk=CreateDesktop(TEXT("Testing"),NULL,NULL,NULL,GENERIC_ALL,NULL);
    SwitchDesktop(hDesk);

    DWORD thr;
    HANDLE thread = CreateThread (0, 0, Testing, 0, 0, &thr);

    WaitForSingleObject (thread, 10000); //Wait 10 seconds before automatically exiting.

    SwitchDesktop(GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId())); //Return to previous desktop
    CloseDesktop(hDesk);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I make the console window be created in the second desktop?

Comment: i suspect the behavior is because console windows are created and maintained by [csrss.exe]. instead of a Windows console window, consider an alternative such as Console2, or the one in Cygwin.

Comment: I suspect it's because a console window is associated with a process rather than with a thread. So you'd have to set the main thread's desktop if you wanted to change the desktop on which the console window is created. It might also have something to do with multiple processes being able to attach to a single console.

Comment: Setting the main thread's desktop doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: That was just supposition. It might be that console windows always go on the desktop that was active when the process started. It could be an oversight. Hard to say.

Comment: @JimMischel, Indeed. It's good to make it clear that the possible solution doesn't work so that more people don't try it and get nothing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is understandable because the one console attached to a process is shared by all threads of that process and it makes sense to put that console on the desktop on which the process was launched rather than dynamically moving the console from desktop to desktop as consoles are allocated and freed by threads that are attached to different desktops. And if such movement of console window is allowed the behavior would be tougher to understand when consoles are shared between processes.

To answer the question on how to associate with a console on a different desktop, I would suggest starting a blank console application window on the target desktop, whose primary responsibility would be to just keep the console window alive. All is has to do is do as

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
Sleep(INFINITE);
return 0;
}
```

And instead of calling AllocConsole, call AttachConsole with the process id of the newly launched process, and then call GetStdHandle to get handle to the console buffer for further calls to WriteConsole.

To launch a new process in a target desktop different from the one the process (at first) is connected to you will have to set the desktop name in the STARTUPINFO structure that would be passed to CreateProcess call.

Comment: It's odd... `dwProcessId` contains a valid PID, but `AllocConsole` fails with what's meant to be the process not existing according to the documentation.

Comment: @chris did you mean AttachConsole. May be the valid pid does not have a console at that time of AttachConsole call.

Comment: Yes, I did mean that, thanks. Oh hey, a `Sleep()` before `AttachConsole` worked. I think the output of `???? Writ` was just me :p

Comment: Yep, it was just me derping and passing a `char *` instead of a `wchar_t *`. Stupid `void *` parameter.